# JavaScript Limitations in Oracle BPEL

Tags: javascript, oracle, bpel, osb

Hi Guys,

I am really confuse about the limitations of Rhino Javascript in Oracle SOA Suite/Oracle Serice Bus. the follow code is working fine in OSB:

```
var dataHoraInicio = new Date (process.dataHoraInicio);
var dataHoraFim = new Date (process.dataHoraFim); 
...
```

In my BPEL project the similar code (as follow) result in 'null values for variables dataHoraInicio and dataHoraFim..

```
var dataHoraInicio = new Date (process.InputVar.dataHoraInicio);      
var dataHoraFim = new Date (process.InputVar.dataHoraFim);    

process.businessFault = {     
 "detalhes" : dataHoraInicio.getTime()    
};
```

.....
[image: Bpel Response]

I need to understand what is happen with the Oracel Javascript Engine....

Any one had tha similar experience?

Regards,
Marcello

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake... In real, it is necessary to youse te complete statemnt of date [YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MSMZ]
Thanks.